# Technique/architecture for multi-tenant apps on GAE

Tags: architecture, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, software-design

Currently the way I have figured out is to have a single instance of the application for each customer and single SQL database instance for that application instance.

This works perfectly but the issue here is that, whenever I make a change to the backend in the staging environment, I have to push the updates manually one by one to each application instance that I've sold to customers. This is fine in an early stage assuming I have only two or three customers, but what if I have 100 customers, or 1000? I don't want to be pushing an update 100 or 1000 times manually.

What I want is an architecture to have one front-end, one back-end and multiple databases instances (where each database instance belongs to a customer).

1. What would be the ideal approach to tackle this problem?
2. What language would be better? (feasibility & security wise) PHP or JAVA?
3. Any framework suggestions?

Comment: Please mention the technology premises. That will be helpful for other answers.

Comment: Any technology is welcomed, as long as it can be deployed on gogole-app-engine